# UITableView not showing in simulator

Tags: autolayout, ios8, xcode6

I created a tableview in Xcode 6 and hooked it up to a view controller. Whenever I try to run the app in the simulator, the tableview is not showing at all and I have no idea why. It's most confusing.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

[image: In Storyboard]

[image: In the simulator]

The class:
    class HomeMenuController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

  func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}


 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {



    return 2
}




 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    var cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("newChecklist") as UITableViewCell

return cell
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I found out how what the problem was.

The VC didn't have the 'First ViewController' option clicked. Explains it all.